# Use Tasker with "OK Google" on Nexus 5

Tags: tasker, google-now, nexus-5

OK guys, I have searched and searched but cannot find an answer to this question.

I want to link the "OK Google" phrase that starts a Google Now search on the Nexus 5 to Tasker, or more specifically the AutoVoice plugin for Tasker.

I can attach the swipe up from the bottom to use AutoVoice rather than Google Now , but I cannot figure out how to make the phrase "OK Google" use AutoVoice.

I read that on the Moto X you can use Tasker to watch for the "Touchless Control" App to become active, and then kill it and start AutoVoice. But the Nexus 5 doesn't have the Touchless Control App, In fact I don't know what process or App is actually listening for the "OK Google" phrase on the Nexus 5.

Can anyone shed any light on how I might make this work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video tutorial on how to get it setup.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6Woh20ullI

**Explanation of Video**

This requires the [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/framework-xposed-rom-modding-modifying-t1574401) and the [Google Now API for it](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-google-search-api-t2554173/post48109086#post48109086). You will need to be rooted to install the Xposed Framework.

First you need to do this:

1. Open Google Now API
2. Click plugin (example AutoVoice)
3. Check "Enable" for Google Now integration

In Tasker you will need to setup something similar to task for task:

1. Create a new Action
2. Create `If` (for action category)
3. For condition select (or type if you cant find) avsource
4. Make sure condition is set to matches
5. type in googlenow for what the condition matches
6. Create whatever action you want for the `If` (need to be familiar with Tasker)
7. Create `End If`

Answer (score -2):

moto x has 2 chips a bit like the M7 chip in iphone 5S which also uses the A7 as its main processor.  The nexus 5 has 1 chip which is why it cant replicate all the goodies of the moto X, although its a much more powerful phone.

This chip uses very little power and has dedicated tasks like geo positioning.  So when you pick up the moto X it knows it is moving, because the 2nd chip is always on, and shows the messages etc.  If the nexus 5 chip was always "listening" for movement, the battery would die in a few hours. So the 2nd chip basically runs on very little power and thus can run constantly.

So the voice commands in moto x will work all the time and you dont need to be in the screen launcher for ok google to work, which cant happen on the N5 without the aforementioned killing of the battery.  So thus there is no touchless control on the N5.

Not sure if that answers your question exactly, but in part - you wont be able to do the Moto X trick on your N5

Comment: Ok google does work on the nexus 5 from the home screens and google now without touching the phone. My question was how to connect it to the AutoVoice/Tasker App. The nexus 5 also has the snap dragon processor with the second low power core, it's just not used in the same way...